# Generic method to get property values with Linq Expression and reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, linq-expressions

Dear Gods of Reflection

I would like to have a generic `GetValue<TEntity, T>` method that can return the following property values given the following `User` class:

```
public class User  
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ClientId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string MobileNumber { get; set; }   
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }

   public Client Client { get; set; }
   public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }

 }
```

Example usage of what `GetValue<TEntity, T>` should be able to do:

```
  var firstName = dataCollector.GetValue<User, string>(x => x.FirstName);
  var client = dataCollector.GetValue<User, Client>(x => x.Client);
  var packages = dataCollector.GetValue<User, List<Package>>(x => x.Packages);

  var packageFirst = dataCollector.GetValue<User, Package>(x => x.Packages[0]);
  var packageName = dataCollector.GetValue<User, string>(x => x.Packages[0].Name);
  var clientName = dataCollector.GetValue<User, string>(x => x.Client.Name);
```

So far I have the following method which works for the first 3 scenarios:

```
 public T GetValue<TEntity, T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> propertyExpression) where TEntity : class
 {
    var response = _responses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetType() == typeof(TEntity)) as TEntity;
    if (response != null)
    {
       var expr = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
       var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
       return (T)prop.GetValue(response);
    }
    return default(T);
  }
```

But it does not work for the last 3 scenarios:

```
  var packageFirst = dataCollector.GetValue<User, Package>(x => x.Packages[0]);
```

Throws: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.`

```
  var packageName = dataCollector.GetValue<User, string>(x => x.Packages[0].Name);
```

Throws: `Object does not match target type.`

```
  var clientName = dataCollector.GetValue<User, string>(x => x.Client.Name);
```

Throws: `Object does not match target type.`

What changes do I need to make to the method?

I shall now sacrifice a USB flash drive whilst awaiting your answers :)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Doesn't compile?  Error message?  if `x.Packages` were empty or null, or if `x.Client` was null you'd get run-time errors.

Comment: We'll need more than that for an answer: who is dataCollector? what type? and where do you want to get with this? I think you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: @DStanley It runs but last 3 throw errors. See my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (response != null)
{
   var expr = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
   var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
   return (T)prop.GetValue(response);
}
```

This *only* works if your expression references a property *directly*, otherwise `propertyExpression.Body` will not be a `MemberExpression` and you'll get a run-time cast error.  The three that don't work do not reference a property directly - the first two reverence a method on top of a property (the indexer) and the last references a nested property.

Since all you want is the value of the expression, though, I *think* you can just do:

```
if (response != null)
{
   Func<TEntity, T> func = propertyExpression.Compile();  
   return func(response);
}
```

If you intended to do *other* things with the expression (like get the *name* of the property), then you'll need to decide if you want to support expressions that don't reference a property directly and add handlers for that.

Comment: Yes I that seems to be the problem. Will try what you suggest. I only need the property values

Comment: Awesome! That works! I guess Compile() does quite a bit of magic in the background. Thought I would need some recursion to get the nested properties

Comment: You can remove the Linq.Expression and Compile() and just do: `  public T GetValue<TEntity, T>(Func<TEntity, T> function) where TEntity : class
        {
            var response = _responses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetType() == typeof(TEntity)) as TEntity;
            if (response != null)
                return function(response);
            return default(T);
        }`

Comment: True, but one benefit of using `Expression` is that if you ever _did_ want to look at the metadata of the expression you could do so without changing the method signature, which would be a breaking change.

Comment: Sure since you don't need to compile the expression at runtime. Whether that's a _significant_ problem or not depends on what else happens when that is called. If so, then a compromise could be to add caching of the compiled expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by Executing your Lambda expression:

```
        if (response != null)
        {
            return propertyExpression.Compile().Invoke(response);
        }
```

Comment: Is there any difference between returning `(T)propertyExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(response);`  and  `func(response)` ?

Comment: i've edited my answer, now IMHO there is no different : as the type is known, there is no sens to use DynamicInvoke wich gona use reflection